# Parsing date in Mon, DD, YYYY format using RegEx in R

Tags: r, regex, date

I am attempting to parse a date from a string of text. I'm assuming the best way to do this is regex, but I haven't quite found a solution that works.

First, I used a CSS selector to grab a date from a website.

```
date <-html_nodes(x=doc, css=".middleheadline+ .topnewsbar b") %>% html_text()
```

This produces:

```
[1] "\r\n        Washington,\r\n        Jan 5, 2011"
```

I want to extract the date itself (here, Jan 5, 2011) from this string. NOTE: the month can be any month, the date can be any date, and the year can be anything from 2011-2015, so I'm trying to find an expression that can generally parse a date in the Mon D[D], YYYY format.

Here's one attempt:

```
date <-str_extract_all(string=date, pattern='[A-Z][a-z]{3,4} ([0-9]{1,2}), [0-9]{4}')
```

This produces `character(0)`

And another:

```
grep("[A-Z][a-z]{3,4} ([0-9]{1,2}), [0-9]{4}", date, value=TRUE)
```

which also produces `character(0)`

Any tips?

Comment: perhaps `grep("\\w{3,4} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}, date, value=TRUE)`  I haven't tested this.  The `\\w` tag will match alpha characters, the `\\d` tag matches digits.

Comment: Is the date always at the end of the string, or always after the last `"\r\n"`?

Comment: I agree with Joshua's implication that we need more info on what the input will look like - not just what the date will look like. The conversion to an actual date type is easy enough as long as we can identify the input. And if it's always at the end of the input string then that makes it *really* easy

Comment: Thanks! The grep solution produces the whole string still, but the strsplit code works. The date is after the `"\r\n"` for many of the sites I'm scraping, but not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
date <-str_extract_all(string=date, pattern='\\w+\\s\\d+(st)?(nd)?(rd)?(th)?,\\s+\\d+')
```

[HERE](https://regex101.com/r/hN4jK9/1) test link.

Comment: Thanks! I had to add double slashes to make it work: `date <-str_extract_all(string=date, pattern='\\w+\\s\\d+(st)?(nd)?(rd)?(th)?,\\s+\\d+')`

Answer (score 5):

You may also try `strsplit()`.  Sometimes I prefer it over a mind-numbing regular expression.

```
test <- c("\r\n        Washington,\r\n        Jan 5, 2011",
    "\r\n        Boston,\r\n        Mar 15, 2015")

vapply(strsplit(test, ".*\n\\s+"), "[", "", 2)
# [1] "Jan 5, 2011"  "Mar 15, 2015"

as.Date(vapply(strsplit(test, ".*\n\\s+"), "[", "", 2), "%b %d, %Y")
# [1] "2011-01-05" "2015-03-15"
```

Answer (score 2):

A function to convert the dates:

```
make_dates <- function(x, date_format=TRUE, split="\n") {
  dates <- lapply(strsplit(x, split), function(x) {
    grep("\\w+ \\d+, \\d+", x, value=T)})

  if(date_format) {
    strptime(gsub("\\s", "", dates), format="%b%d,%Y")
  } else { gsub(".*?(\\w.*)", "\\1", dates)}
}

test <- c("\r\n        Washington,\r\n        Jan 5, 2011",
       "\r\n        Boston,\r\n        Mar 15, 2015")

make_dates(test)
#[1] "2011-01-05 EST" "2015-03-15 EDT"
make_dates(test, FALSE)
#[1] "Jan 5, 2011"  "Mar 15, 2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will return a date in a string in a variety of MDY formats, with a variety of separators.  Be sure to set the `case insensitve` option in your procedure.

It does some rudimentary error checking, but it will allow two digit years; and would also allow a date such as Feb 31, 2015

```
\b((?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[a-z]*|(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))(?:\s*([- /.])\s*)(?:(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(?:st|nd|rd|th)?),?\2((?:19|2\d)?\d{2})\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would suffice:

```
[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2}, 201[1-4]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eW3jV6/1

What month's abbreviation is 5 or 4 characters long? Your regex is failing because you have `[A-Z][a-z]{3,4}` which says an uppercase alpha character followed by three or four lowercase alpha characters. I'm unfamiliar with a month that has a 5 character abbreviation.

Your string `Jan` is 3 characters long but only 2 of those characters are lowercase.

Demo of your current regex: https://regex101.com/r/bJ6gT3/1

If there is a possibility of multiple spaces between the month and day and/or year add in `\h+`; or if there can be no spaces make it `\h*`.

Comment: Some of the dates use the 3 char abbreviation, whereas others are full month names (between 4 and 9 characters). I'm trying to find something that will deal with all permutations of the month name.

Comment: You could use grouping something like `(Jan(uary)?|Feb(urary)?|Mar(ch)?)` etc.. then the day and year check.